# RadTabStrip postback

Tags: asp.net, radgrid

I have a RadTabStrip. I dodn't want post back on all rad tabs.but i want postback on particular tab is it possible.Is it possible to use any control here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you should use Telerik ajaxupdatecontrol.
[More info is here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-ajaxupdatedcontrol-properties.html)

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxMan" runat="server" 
    DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="" EventName="">
            <UpdatedControls>
                //this control wil postack
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="" LoadingPanelID="ralpSinglCont" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="ralpSinglCont" runat="server" 
    Skin="Transparent" Transparency="40">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```